# How to solve "CoreAnimation: rendering error 506" error?

Tags: macos, imagekit

I have develop a mac program, it works fine when I use it. But, sometimes when I close the program, I get some error messages in console output like below:

CoreAnimation: rendering error 506
--ImageKit Error: error before reading pixels: 506
--ImageKit Error: error after reading pixels: 506

This does not occur everytime, seems like it just happen randomly. What operation may cause this problem? How can I figure out it? I have no idea at all. Please give me some advise about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may be hardware problems. There are TONS of these images on Apple discussion forums: https://www.google.com/search?q=--ImageKit+Error%3A+error+before+reading+pixels%3A+506&oq=--ImageKit+Error%3A+error+before+reading+pixels%3A+506&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&q=+site:discussions.apple.com+%22--ImageKit+Error:+error+before+reading+pixels:+506%22&sa=X&ei=06mYUJ6EBeTZ4QSSk4HgCw&ved=0CCYQrQIwAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3a283cf18b467b8d&bpcl=37189454&biw=1238&bih=726